# Repeated column in mapping for entity with @ManyToOne

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities which is giving me error on creation of datasource

Entity1

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "person_details")
public class PersonDetails {
    @Id
    private String pid;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "exist_flag")
    private String existFlag;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pid", nullable = false)
    private List<AddressDetails> addressDetails;
}
```

Entity 2 | **EDIT 1**

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "address_details")
public class AddressDetails {

    private String street;

    @Column(name = "address_exist_flag")
    private String addressExistFlag;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private PersonDetails personDetails;

}
```

Getting error as below:

I am getting error as "No identifier specified for entity: AddressDetails".

How to resolve in such case? Can we use spring data jpa having OneToMany mapping in such case where one entity do not have primary key ?

Comment: is it possible for you to provide the table column details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are using the same column name for 2 different columns.

```
@Id
private String pid;
```

and

```
@JoinColumn(name = "pid"
```

means that you want both your id column and your foreign key column to be named "pid", hence the error. I would suggest using a name like "addressDetailsFk" for the JoinColumn attribute.

Comment: I added as you have told - @OneToMany(mappedBy = "personDetails", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AddressDetails> addressDetails;        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private PersonDetails personDetails;      Still same error "Repeated column in mapping for entity"

Comment: @user2800089 right, I see now that you used the same name for your foreign key column and id column. You have to use a new column name on @JoinColumn(name = "pid", its usually called something like "personDetailsFk".

Comment: @Jepzz I checked the actual DB data and found that AddressDetails table do not have any primary key which makes pid column as a normal one. In such scenario, would it be possible to utilize spring data jpa

Comment: @user2800089 you should look into fixing that (for performance) but the framework you use shouldn't care about that as it just sees them as columns.

Comment: I can't change that as those tables belong to legacy system where I don't have access. If I remove  @  Id private String pid; from AddressDetails and re-run, application is failing with "No identifier specified for entity:". Going to update my question as well

Comment: @user2800089 You have to mark something as id, it shouldn't have to be a primary key field in the db so that should work anyway, but I might be wrong.

Comment: @user2800089 if you have further problems with pk and id you should put that into a new question so there can be an approved answer, stackoverflow is not made for multiple questions in one post.

Comment: you are right anything could be marked as Id and that solved my issue. How should I select that as answer?

Comment: @user2800089 I edited the answer to actually answer the headline of your question, you should accept this and if you want to submit your other problem you should create a new thread.